# Open with Google Docs in Google Document Viewer not working | Error

Tags: onedrive

[image][image]I am trying to integrate the OneDrive file picker Javascript v 7.2 SDK into my Angular JS 1.6 web app. When I click on the "Open OneDrive", it opens up a pop-up window and shows the login screen. However, after logging in, I get redirected back to my web app in the popup window instead of showing the file picker. This happens randomly and sometimes it works showing me the files in the file picker.

I have followed the exact same steps mentioned in their documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/open-file

I have a large application and since the issue is random, I am unable to reproduce this on a standalone app. Any inputs are much appreciated.

Comment: So, this turned out that its an issue in the Microsoft SDK which I reported and was fixed in the latest release of their SDK. However, I was still puzzled why or how this issue wasn't experienced by nobody else. If your facing this issue, just upgrade to their latest SDK.